# ffplay - error seeking

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I was trying to get top video and bottom audio waveform. However i couldn't scrub/seek back and forth with left/right mouse. A normal ffplay command works for seeking.

I got the error while seeking in my shell running :

Example1

```
ffplay -f lavfi \
"amovie=abc.mp4, asplit [a][out1]; [a]showvolume=f=255:b=2:w=720:h=68 [av]; \
movie=abc.mp4, split [v][out2]; [v]scale=720x360[vs]; [vs][av]vstack=2"
```

Example2

```
ffplay -f lavfi \
"amovie=abc.mp4, asplit [waves][out1]; [waves]pan=1c|c0=c0,showwaves=s=720x100[av]; \
movie=abc.mp4, split [v][out2]; [v]scale=720x360[vs]; [vs][av]vstack=2"
```

Answer (score 2):

ffplay only seeks on regular file or network-fed inputs. It cannot seek on inputs opened via filters.

Comment: hmm..then how come you can seek via the below video filter example :
`ffplay -i http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi  -vf "split[a][b];[a]format=gray,waveform,split[c][d];[b]pad=iw:ih+256[padded];[c]geq=g=1:b=1[red];[d]geq=r=1:b=1,crop=in_w:220:0:16[mid];[red][mid]overlay=0:16[wave];[padded][wave]overlay=0:H-h" `

Comment: The input wasn't opened via a filter.